# ShipStation WooCommerce Integration error

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

An error occurred attempting to update orders: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.example.com'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the remote domain can't resolve via the script, check and see if it loads in your browser. If it does, then contact your hosting company as there may be a problem with routing from their servers.

If the domain doesn't resolve in your browser either, you will need to contact Shipstation for a solution.